# How to make one LI with 2px four-side border, when it's in a UL "table" with 1px borders (made with -1px top and left margins)

Tags: css, border, margin

Here is my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/aWmku/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li style="border: 2px solid blue;">5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    width:400px;
}

li {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    width: 129px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
}
```

There is table made with unordered list items, using **-1px top and left margins** for 1px grey borders to collapse. I tried to make 2px blue border for one of the cells. When you zoom in, there is **blue 2px top and left borders** on 5th list item, but it's **overridden by grey 1px border of neighbour items on right and bottom**.

What I'm trying to achieve: create 2px blue border on one (clicked/focused) cell, that is positioned it the cell exactly like on [this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npqa6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to position it above the neighbours.

```
li {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    width: 129px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

li:nth-child(5) {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/aWmku/1/)

The trick is to set to the element a z-index greater than the neighbours

(I have updated the style to work thru the CSS; I don't like inline styles :-)

Answer (score 0):

But using the: nth-child () with css is not supported in IE <9, you can do this via javascript, something like this: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r_mayrink/aWmku/4/):

```
$('ul li').eq(4).css("border","2px solid blue");
```